# "Differential element" looking object in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity

I am currently a 3rd year undergraduate electronic engineering student and I am very interested in physics. I have completed a course in dynamics, calculus I, calculus II and calculus III.

I have often read articles on general relativity and in the mathematics, specifically associated with integration, I have seen a "differential element" looking object; ds^2. What is this object?

I would also appreciate it if anyone could explain what a metric in mathematics/physics is and in what topics of these subjects is it used.

I have no knowledge in general relativity or tensor calculus other than what I read and have only self studied very basic special relativity.

All answers regarding this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $(ds)^2=(dx)^2+(dy)^2+(dz)^2-c^2(dt)^2$

Comment: @Dr.MV that's only in flat spacetime (which OP may have knowledge of from self studying SR)

Comment: @Mark Mark (my name also), then fine $$(ds)^2=g_{ij}(dx)^i (dx)^j$$where $g_{ij}$ is called the metric.  It is a tensor of rank $2$.